# Object assignment does not work in this angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

Inside my angularjs controller, I try to assign an object into a $scope.XX object. For some reason, it cannot work. Here is a simplified version of the code inside the angularjs controller.

```
    $scope.XXX = {};
    polling_interval_ms = 100;          

    var poll = function (ChartObj, polling_interval_ms) {
        var processedObj = {};
        processedObj = processDataChart(data_Chart); //data_Chart is object that contains data that changes in real-time
        ChartObj = Object.assign(processedObj);
        console.log(ChartObj);

        $timeout(function () {
            poll(ChartObj, polling_interval_ms)
        }, polling_interval_ms);
    };

    poll($scope.XXX, polling_interval_ms);
    console.log($scope.XXX);
```

The strange part is the output of `console.log(ChartObj);` shows that data has been assigned to the object. However, the output of `console.log($scope.XXX)` is empty. I was expecting `$scope.XXX` to contain same data as `ChartObj`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript all parameters in function is reference. So when you change reference - you **not** change referenced object.

In your case you can use [Object.assgin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in a bit different way

```
Object.assign(ChartObj, processedObj);
```

because

> The **Object.assign()** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Or pass wrapper for object XXX, in this case it a `$scope`

```
$scope.ChartObj = {};
polling_interval_ms = 100;          

var poll = function (wrapper, polling_interval_ms) {
    var processedObj = {};
    processedObj = processDataChart(data_Chart); //data_Chart is object that contains data that changes in real-time
    wrapper.ChartObj = Object.assign(processedObj);
    console.log(wrapper.ChartObj);

    $timeout(function () {
        poll(wrapper, polling_interval_ms)
    }, polling_interval_ms);
};

poll($scope, polling_interval_ms);
console.log($scope.ChartObj);
```

Comment: Wonderful. I wish I can given you more points. Wonderful!!! I spent hours while you took minutes. You are a genius!!

Comment: @user16891328, just be more attentive when reading the documentation for the function :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$scope.XXX
```

instead of ChartObj because

your are assigning value to

```
ChartObj
```

and

```
$scope.XXX
```

is not a refrence type